# using telegram api gradle sync failed: ndk bundle

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, build.gradle, telegram, ndk-build

I'm trying to build an application using telegram API on Android Studio. I've some problems about NDK or ndk path. All of things in Android Studio are updated. I downloaded the telegram source code and set up the bots. When I try to compile the source code on Android studio, get an error like the one shown in the picture in the link. The source code and SDK under files in root directory. Thank you for your supporting.

http://i.hizliresim.com/dB2Xr4.png

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error in the screenshot. Please copy the build output as text and update your question.